# Loop batch file for X minutes?

Tags: batch-file

I am very new to batch files, having mostly coded in Matlab for years. I would simply like to loop some code I have written for a set number of minutes. In pseudocode:

```
While elapsedTime<timeLimit
    Run Code
```

How do I declare the variables elapsedTime (which would be a time counter that runs throughout the While loop) and timeLimit (just a value in seconds)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using batch you could do this:

```
@echo off
set /p min=Set minutes: 
set /a sec=%min% * 60
timeout %sec%
```

Answer (score 0):

Calculating with time is difficult in batch (not impossible, just difficult).
Here is another approach: creating a dummy file, start an additional (independent) process which waits a certain time and then deletes the file.
The original process can loop until the file disappears:

```
@echo off
break> timer.tmp
start /min cmd /c "timeout 5 & del timer.tmp"
:loop
  echo waiting...
  timeout 1 >nul
if exist timer.tmp goto :loop
echo done waiting.
```

Just adapt the timeout to the desired time (5 seconds in my example)